# Returning values from multiple CSV columns to Python dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to call additional CSV columns to my Python dictionary below.

The example works fine for the return of one set of values (column), but I need to return values for 2 columns that are not next to each other.

```
import csv

# set csv file and path
allrows=list(csv.reader(open('C:/Data/Library/Peter/123.csv')))

# Extract the first row as keys for a columns dictionary
columns=dict([(x[0],x[1:]) for x in zip(*allrows)])

# Then extracting column 3 from all rows with a certain criterion in column 4
matchingrows=[rownum for (rownum,value) in enumerate(columns['Status']) if value == 'Keep']
print map(columns['book_ref'].__getitem__, matchingrows)

**sample from 123.csv**
book_id  TYPE   book_ref    Status
607842    3     9295        Keep
607844    4     7643        Keep
607846    3     2252        Retire
607856    3     7588        Keep
```

Returns values from column 3 correctly

```
['9644', '4406', '7643', '2252', '7588']
```

But how to return values from column 1 and 3?

```
['607842':'4406', '607844':'7643', '607846':'2252', '607856':'7588']
```

I also tried this but I could not get what I wanted there either.

```
##import csv
##with open('C:/Data/Library/Peter/123.csv') as f:
##    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
##    for row in reader:
##        print row
''' 
{'Status': 'Retire', 'TYPE': '3', 'book_ref': '2397', 'book_id': '607838'}
{'Status': 'Keep', 'TYPE': '12', 'book_ref': '9644', 'book_id': '607839'}
{'Status': 'Retire', 'TYPE': '4', 'book_ref': '9295', 'book_id': '607841'}
{'Status': 'Keep', 'TYPE': '3', 'book_ref': '4406', 'book_id': '607842'}
{'Status': 'Retire', 'TYPE': '4', 'book_ref': '1798', 'book_id': '607843'}
{'Status': 'Keep', 'TYPE': '4', 'book_ref': '7643', 'book_id': '607844'}
{'Status': 'Retire', 'TYPE': '3', 'book_ref': '6778', 'book_id': '607845'}
{'Status': 'Keep', 'TYPE': '3', 'book_ref': '2252', 'book_id': '607846'}
{'Status': 'Retire', 'TYPE': '4', 'book_ref': '7910', 'book_id': '607855'}
{'Status': 'Keep', 'TYPE': '3', 'book_ref': '7588', 'book_id': '607856'}
```

Comment: Have you tried **csv.DictReader** ([https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html]). With correct mapping, I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, but no. (your shortcut returns 404 as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or try this:

```
import csv
result={}
with open('C:/Temp/123.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Status']=='Keep':
            result.update({row['book_id']:row['book_ref']})
```

which will produce:

```
{'607842': '9295', '607844': '7643', '607856': '7588'}
```

Comment: Thank you that works for me. The other responses below are appreciated but do not address the 'Status' requirement.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply try like this:

```
with open("123.csv") as f:
    my_list = []
    next(f)
    for x in f:
        x = x.strip().split()
        my_list.append((x[0],x[2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
zipList = zip(*allrows[1:])
print dict(zip(zipList[0], zipList[2]))
```

Output:

```
{'607842': '9295', '607856': '7588', '607844': '7643', '607846': '2252'}
```